# how to apply parent child relation in big query with array

Tags: google-bigquery

If we have input table is like this.

INPUT ::

| parent | child | name | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| raju | naveen | a | NA |
| raju | ravi | b | NA |
| raju | ravi | c | NA |
| raju | ram | d | NA |
| raju | ram | e | NA |
| raju | ram | f | NA |
| smith | rahul | g | NA |

i need a query to get the output in this format in Bigquery

OUTPUT ::

| Parent | child_details |
| --- | --- |
| raju | [{naveen,a,NA},{ravi,b,NA},{ravi,c,NA},{ram,d,NA},{ram,e,NA},{ram,f,NA}] |
| smith | [{rahul,g,NA}] |

i need a query to get the output in this format in Bigquery

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`STRING_AGG`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#string_agg) function. Below is an example.

#### Query

```
WITH
dataset AS (
  SELECT 'A' as parent, '01' as child, 'a' as detail_field_01, 'NA' as detail_field_02,
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '02', 'b', 'NA'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '02', 'c', 'NA'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '03', 'd', 'NA'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '03', 'e', 'NA'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A', '03', 'f', 'NA'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', '04', 'g', 'NA'
)
SELECT
    parent,
    CONCAT('[',
        STRING_AGG(
            CONCAT('{', child, ',', detail_field_01, ',', detail_field_02, '}'),
            ','  # delimiter
            ORDER BY  detail_field_01 ASC
        ), ']'
    ) as child_details
FROM dataset
GROUP BY parent
;
```

#### Results

[image]